# Android image stuck on top

Tags: android, image, gridview, android-asynctask

I have a gridview being populated from db. When I open some images they get stuck at the top of the layout. What could be causing that?

I noticed that some images open directly in the middle of the layout that is what I really want. And some images just "fall" in the right position after I double tap to zoom them.

Gridview activity

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_grid_view);

    TextView id = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.i_id);

    Intent i = getIntent();
    i_id = i.getStringExtra(TAG_ID);

    id.setText(i_id);

    mGridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView);
    mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

    //Initialize with empty data
    mGridData = new ArrayList<>();
    mGridAdapter = new GridViewAdapter(this, R.layout.grid_item_layout, mGridData);
    mGridView.setAdapter(mGridAdapter);

    //Grid view click event
    mGridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
            //Get item at position
            GridItem item = (GridItem) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);

            Intent intent = new Intent(GridViewActivity.this, DetailsActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("image", item.getImage());
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    //Start download
    new AsyncHttpTask().execute(FEED_URL);
    mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

Details activity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_details);

    Intent i = getIntent();
    String image = i.getStringExtra("image");

    //Set image url
    imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.grid_item_image);
    Picasso.with(DetailsActivity.this).load(image).into(imageView);
    mAttacher = new PhotoViewAttacher(imageView);

    Uri bmpUri = getLocalBitmapUri(imageView);

    shareIntent = new Intent();
    shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    shareIntent.setType("image/*");
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, bmpUri);


}
```

Gridview.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#f0f0f0">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/i_id"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="IDDD"
    android:visibility="gone"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/ilustrativas"
    android:id="@+id/ilustrativas"
    android:layout_above="@+id/likes_count"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:textStyle="italic" />

<GridView
    android:id="@+id/gridView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/ilustrativas"
    android:columnWidth="100dp"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:verticalSpacing="5dp"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:clickable="true"/>

<ProgressBar
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/progressBar"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:visibility="gone"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Details.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/main_background"
android:background="#000">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/grid_item_image"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

GridItem.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
android:background="#f1f1f1"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="5dp">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/grid_item_image"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:layout_height="100dp" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the error by myself. I don´t know why but PhotoviewAttacher was causing the problem. Just removed it and used this class https://github.com/MikeOrtiz/TouchImageView